# Converting 1-d array to 2d

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I am trying to understand this code:

```
void stencil(const int nx, const int ny, const int width, const int height,
             double* image, double* tmp_image)
{
  for (int j = 1; j < ny + 1; ++j) {
    for (int i = 1; i < nx + 1; ++i) {
      tmp_image[j + i * height] =  image[j     + i       * height] * 3.0 / 5.0;
      tmp_image[j + i * height] += image[j     + (i - 1) * height] * 0.5 / 5.0;
      tmp_image[j + i * height] += image[j     + (i + 1) * height] * 0.5 / 5.0;
      tmp_image[j + i * height] += image[j - 1 + i       * height] * 0.5 / 5.0;
      tmp_image[j + i * height] += image[j + 1 + i       * height] * 0.5 / 5.0;
    }
  }
}
```

The 1-d array notation is very confusing. I am trying to convert it to a 2-d notation (which I find easier to read). Could  someone point me in the right direction as to how I can accomplish this?

Comment: It would help a lot if you gave an example of a **small** array you'd like to convert from one representation to the other.

Comment: It's obvious that the 1D array gets stored in a column-major format, and the value that always gets multiplied by `height` is the column number, and what's added to it is the row number. Which part of this is unclear to you?

Comment: ok, so the second line in the loops is essentially this: `tmp_image[j][i] += image[j][i-1]*0.5/5.0`?

Comment: As Sam said - but do read [Row- and column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) to get a better understanding.

Comment: All the += statements seem superfluous. It should be a single expression.

Comment: Regarding performance you shouldn't convert it. 1d arrays are usually better because it's one block in memory. 2d arrays are arrays of pointers pointing to different places in memory.

Comment: Are you using a C compiler or a C++ compiler?

Comment: Looks dodgy.  I'd expect `for (int j = 1; j < ny - 1; ++j) {`.  To me the index looks like it will eventually index out of bounds: UB.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica  Yep, it's odd. Note that the argument `width` isn't used and how does `height` relate to `ny`. Usually you only need one. And normally in something like this `ny` and `nx` determine the length of the 1D array.  Very odd structure. The length needs to be at least `ny+(nx+1)*height+1`

Answer (score 0):

All this code is doing is creating a new image from an original image by taking 60% from the corresponding pixel and 10% from each neighboring pixel.

When you see `tmp_image[j + i * height]`, read it as `tmp_image[i][j]`.

Changing the code to literally use 2D syntax may require knowing at least one of the dimensions at compile time, whereas now it is a runtime argument.  So that might be a non-starter, unless you're using C++ and want to write or use a matrix class instead of plain arrays.